# data:, at the search bar in selenium python test

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Look at this.
When I fire test in selenium python I get just  `data:,` in search bar. Where lay the problem? I attach my files on github.

I have to mark, at the friday I worked at this and I didn't notice any error
https://github.com/WIKse96/seleniumProblem

I tried test, and i expected requested site will open

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When I run test, I get `data:,` at the search bar. There should be tested site url